# Create multiple checkboxes using the same CSS style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want to use a CSS styleheet for 3 different checkboxes on the same HTML page.I'm unsure how to declare the location of the checkboxes to make them all in line with the text. Here is my CSS stylesheet for the checkbox:

```
input[type=checkbox] 
{
visibility: hidden;
} 

.checkboxOne {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #484848;
border-radius: 100%;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
height: 40px;
margin: -30px 200px;
position: relative;
width: 40px;
}

.checkboxOne input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #6E0000;
}

.checkboxOne  label:before {
content:'N';
padding:6px;
color:#000000;
    display: block;
padding: 4px;
text-align: center;
}

.checkboxOne input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content:'Y';
padding:6px;
color:#FFFFFF;
    display:block;
padding: 4px;
text-align: center;
}


.checkboxOne label {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #DDDDDD;
border-radius: 100px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) inset;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
height: 30px;
left: 5px;
position: absolute;
top: 5px;
transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
width: 30px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

I know that margin is the location of the checkbox hard coded. I am hoping there is a way to make the checkboxes location inline right after the text in the html document, like this:

```
   Did you eat breakfast? <div class="checkboxOne">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxInput"></label>
  </div><br>
    Did you eat lunch? <div class="checkboxOne">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput2" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxInput2"></label>
  </div><br>
    Did you eat dinner? <div class="checkboxOne">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput3" name="" />
  <label for="checkboxInput3"></label>
  </div><br>
```

Comment: use inline element like `span` instead of `div`, or set `div` inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do a proper form! Sorted out what you want now.

**Correct answer** Look at the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5s8/2/

HTML

```
<form>

<fieldset>


<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput" name="" />
<label for="checkboxInput">Did you eat breakfast?</label>


<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput2" name="" />
<label for="checkboxInput2">Did you eat lunch?</label>        


<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="checkboxInput3" name="" />
<label for="checkboxInput3">Did you eat dinner?</label>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

A pinch of CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
display:none;
}

label {
float: left;
clear: left;
width: 200px;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label:after
{
content: 'N';
background: #F00;
float: right;

}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after
{
content: 'Y';
background: #FF0;

}
```

Comment: Not quite what I meant. I want the questions each to be on separate lines with their corresponding checkbox right next to them. I am using the CSS to style the checkbox because this is for a mobile application.

Comment: Here you are. Look at the fiddle now, I changed the answer.

Comment: That's the setup I want exactly, but is there a way to implement that with my CSS? My way to fix this is to make 2 new checkboxes in the CSS and change their locations by hard coding, but that will have a lot of repeated code and I want to do a more efficient way.

Comment: Scratch that! Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Wa5s8/2/ 

You can fiddle with the css :after inputs to get the form you want.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could try:
HTML

```
         <div class="row">
           <input type="radio" /> <span>Radio title </span>
         </div>
```

CSS:

```
         .row{ display:block;}
         .row span{margin:0 0 0 10px;}
```